# How to check if an ideal generated by two elements is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I have a question about ideals generated by two elements. I've searched MathStackexchange and found some related posts, but I haven't been able to understand how it all works.

The question is in general:

> 1. How can I show that an ideal generated by two prime elements, is indeed prime in a UFD.
> 2. More specific I want to show that in $\Bbb C[x,y]$ the ideals generated by $(x-i, y+3)$ and $(x+i,y+3)$ are in fact prime ideals.

My initial approach was: $\Bbb C[x,y]$ is a UFD. In a UFD every irreducible element is prime. In a UFD every prime element generates a prime ideal. But I'm not sure I can use that argument when my ideal is generated by *two* prime elements.

I know that I can check that $I$ is a prime ideal by checking that $R/I$ is an integral domain, but I'm not sure how to do that in my example. Can anyone show me?

I would be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map $\mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(x,y) \mapsto f(i, -3)$, i.e. evaluating the polynomial at $x=i, y=-3$.

Show this is a surjective homomorphism. Show the kernel is exactly the ideal $I=(x-i, y+3)$. Then you can use the first isomorphism theorem to show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ is a field, and thus $I$ is a maximal (and therefore prime) ideal.

In general, though, we cannot assume that starting with two prime ideals will give us a new prime ideal. For example, the ideals $(3)$ and $(5)$ are both prime in the integers, but their product is not.

Comment: Can you fix the typo at the beginning where there is a 'u' instead of a 'y'. It is quite simple but it was a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @üzeyir Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed it.

Comment: In the last paragraph do you mean to consider the sum of two prime ideals instead of the product?  (So that $(3) + (5)$ is not prime because it's the unit ideal?)  In that case, you could also consider examples such as $(y, y-x^2)$ is not prime (the quotient has nilpotents) or $(y, y-x^2+1)$ is not prime (the quotient has non-nilpotent zero divisors).